# split by crlf using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, split, newline

Need help how to proper split a string by crlf
below is the code:

```
 Dim str As String = "Hello" & vbCrLf & "World"
 Dim parts As String() = str.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray)
 For Each part As String In parts
  MsgBox(part)
 Next
```

Output

```
 Hello

 World
```

I want to get rid the blank space in between the two.

Hello
   World

Comment: Do you mean that you want them both to be in the same message box?

Comment: I want to get rid the blank space between Hello and World

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to support all kinds of newlines (CR, LF, CR LF) and don’t need blank lines, you can split on both characters and make use of the `String.Split` option that stops it from producing empty entries:

```
str.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

(This also produces an empty array if the input is empty.)

If you know you have consistent CR LF newlines and you want to preserve blank lines, you can split on the entire delimiter:

```
str.Split({ControlChars.CrLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: RemoveEmptyEntries was also a great tip to throw in there.. thanks

Comment: Answer from KekuSemau is actually better, as it doesn't have the collateral of removing extra entries. The answer from Ry here actually splits on each character in vbcrlf and then throws out the extra lines, which is inefficient and ugly

Comment: @Jack - White I didn't do a performance analysis and unless the performance difference was substantial, in this situation I would offer that a strongly typed native method would be my preference over one that is not.  JMHO

Answer (score 6):

The given answer splits on any `cr` OR `lf` and removes blanks; that works ok for the given case, but it would remove 'real' empty lines as well (and feels unclean to me).

Alternative:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(str, vbCrLf)
```

(note that the second string is a regex-pattern, special chars would have to be escaped)

Answer (score 0):

This code will split on line-feed, new line or both(vbCrLf). It will not remove empty lines.

```
    Dim arr() As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(text, "(\r\n|\r|\n)", _
                          RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
```